# Difference between JavaScript and Postgres Epoch

Tags: javascript, postgresql, datetime

I would have thought these two statements would have returned the same value:

**Javascript (Chrome)**

```
new Date(2018, 3, 1).getTime() /1000;
=> 1522533600
```

**Postgres**

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2018-03-01 00:00:00 ');
=> 1519858800.0
```

As you can see there is a huge difference. What am I missing here?

**Timezone information**

Both queries are performed in the same timezone, confirmed as below.

Postgres

```
SELECT EXTRACT(TIMEZONE FROM now())/3600.0;
=> 2.0
```

Javascript

```
new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
-120
```

**Solution**

Thank you @yelliver and @Vao Tsun, the problem was that Javascript starts the month with zero. Confirming:

```
new Date(2018, 2, 1).getTime() /1000;
=> 1519858800
```

Comment: What's with the downvotes?

Comment: Reading the documentation would have helped: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date (pay attention to the `month` parameter).

Comment: @ardochhigh adapt you post to have March against JS call please

Comment: Thank you @deceze, in fact I did read the documentation, and have been struggling with this problem for over an hour. I obviously missed the point that JS starts the month differently. I think SO is a fantastic tool, but it would benefit from less negative energy. Wouldn't it have been just as easy to state the answer? Have a nice day.

Comment: @ardochhigh I have to admit that posts concerning javascript suffer from a lot of negative energy lately.

Comment: @ardochhigh but it's still one hour diff according to code you pasted - are you saying they match?..

Comment: yes they match, see the posted solution in the original post.

Comment: t=# SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2018-03-01 00:00:00+01:00');
     date_part
    ------------
     1519858800
    (1 row)

so I still don't understand why you have time zone `+2` and get 

    SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2018-03-01 00:00:00 ');
    => 1519858800.0

Comment: That's the timezone offset of the server ... I wanted to help any posters by confirming there was no difference according to timezone. Both the Javascript and SQL commands were run under the same offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new Date(2018, 3, 1)  = Sun Apr 01 2018
```

It's April, not March